# Program not going into tthe IF condition. Involve struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement, visual-c++, struct

```
    BBQ findBBQ(string date)
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
              {
                  if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
                  {
                      cout << "Avail" << endl;
                      return pits[i][j];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      cout << "Unavail" << endl;
                      return pits[i][j];
                  }
              }
          }
     }
```

My problem lies in IF condition. I am trying to enter a date, and have the program run through the array of dates I have initialized and print if such a date is available. For some reason, the program only enter the IF for the first entry in the array once it found a match, and ignores the others in the array despite them matching as well.

Comment: What's the point of looping if you're just going to return on the first iteration?  I.e., you don't want to return in your `else` clause.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

```
BBQ findBBQ(string date)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
          {
              if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
              {
                  cout << "Avail" << endl;
                  return pits[i][j];
              }


              // Error in logic.
              // If the date of the first item does not match the
              // input date, you enter the else block and return 
              // right away. This block needs to be moved. 
              else
              {
                  cout << "Unavail" << endl;
                  return pits[i][j];
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

Fix:

```
BBQ findBBQ(string date)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
          {
              if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
              {
                  cout << "Avail" << endl;
                  return pits[i][j];
              }
          }
      }

      cout << "Unavail" << endl;
      return <<<something that represents not found>>>;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not really looking past the first position in your dates array. You probably want something a bit more like this

```
BBQ* findBBQ(string date)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
            {
                cout << "Avail" << endl;
                return &pits[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Unavail" << endl;
    return NULL;
}
```

BTW, I've changed your method signature to return a pointer. You're not using the result in the above code so maybe it doesn't matter, but a pointer is going to have less overhead than a return-by-copy.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is about your function: You return from whether you find or not, so your logic is not correct here in else statement. You are not tracing every element of list. Quickest solution is this:

```
BBQ findBBQ(string date)
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
              {
                  if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
                  {
                      cout << "Avail" << endl;
                      return pits[i][j];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      cout << "Unavail" << endl;
                     // return pits[i][j];
                  }
              }
          }
     }
```

But Why do you need to return BBQ in this fuction? Also you are printing 3 "Avail" or "UnAvail" for every month. Maybe you can do like this:

```
void findBBQ(string date)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
          {
              if (pits[i][j].cal_date == date)
              {
                  cout << "Avail" << endl;
                  return;
              }
          }
      }
      cout << "Unavail" << endl;
 }
```